# Achieve centering with overflow without position absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the effect of having a centered image that flows past its containing div's borders, but without using position: absolute, because it hides the header buttons behind it. Is there any clean way to do this without just using old-school absolute position with all the elements (which would be a real pain if I try to do any kind of responsiveness at all)?

Relevant code:

```
.container {
    max-width: 60rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

.container.no-border {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}

#logo {
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: -75px; 
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bH35r/

P.S. I'm willing to utilize pretty much anything as long as it does the job cleanly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block;`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bH35r/19/)**

HTML :

```
<div class="section header">
    <div class="container no-border">
        <a class="header" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="header" href="#">News</a>
        <a class="header" href="#">Teams</a>
        <div class="logo_wrap">
            <img id="logo" src="http://equineclub.zachschristmaslist.info/images/pennant.png"/>
        </div>
        <a class="header" href="#">Apparel</a>
        <a class="header" href="#">Sponsorship</a>
        <a class="header" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: #191A18;
}

.section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
}

.section.header {
    background-image: url('../images/background.png');
    background-position: 50% 90%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 1rem #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    max-width: 60rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

.container.no-border {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}

.container.logo {
    background-image: url('../images/main-image.jpg');
    background-position: 50% 20%;
    min-height: 20rem;
}

a.header {
    color: white;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

#logo {
    width: 150px;

}
.logo_wrap{
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 5.5rem;
    vertical-align:top;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: That's...fantastic! So setting the overflow of the image div to visible allowed it to supersede the containing div's border?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS background image.

```
.container {
    max-width: 60rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    background-image:url(....);
    background-repeat-no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px; <--- adjust accordingly.
}
```

In general, images that are part of the UI (not the content) should be CSS backgrounds, not inline images anyway.

Comment: Interesting. And then add overflow: visible, I'd assume? Also, how would I then go about centering the other header buttons around it? Brute force?

Comment: Float one set left, the other right. Use a min-width on the wrapping element to ensure it doesn't shrink to the point of overlapping.